# Pass js array to php and parse it

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, post

So this is my php function. First I get the variable

```
    $this->sphotoRepository->save($command->sphoto, $status->id, $command->label, $command->sphoto_categories, $command->sphoto_tagged_users, $command->u18);
```

Which passes to the final function

```
public function save(UploadedFile $file = null, $statusId, $label, $sphoto_categories, $sphoto_tagged_users, $u18)
....
if (isset($sphoto_categories) && !empty($sphoto_categories)) {
            foreach ($sphoto_categories as $sphoto_category_id)
            {
                $category = StatusPhotoCategory::findOrFail($sphoto_category_id);
                $sphoto->categories()->attach($category->id);
            }
        }
```

And here is how I pass my data

```
post.sphoto_categories = Array("2");
```

What I would expect as a result (Postman form submit does confirm it. But I am using sphoto_categories[] ... in there to create the array. Can't do that in JS)

```
'sphoto_categories' => 
 array (
    0 => '2',
  )
```

What I get when form submit via js

```
'sphoto_categories' => '["3"]'
```

Comment: And the question is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you receive is JSON representation of Array. You need to do `json_decode()` to get array which you expect.

So add the following lines to the code. Do the validation that variable is decoded correctly. json_decode returns `null` if JSON is not well formatted. You can check the value of `json_last_error()` to get idea what went wrongly.

```
$categoriesArray = json_decode($command->sphoto_categories);
// Validation.
$this->sphotoRepository->save($command->sphoto, $status->id, $command->label, $categoriesArray, $command->sphoto_tagged_users, $command->u18);
```

Comment: Working so far, but how to catch exception? Because it seems like i cannot catch it with try/catch

Comment: There is no exception. You need to check the following `null === $categoriesArray` and handle the error in this case.

Comment: Im checking is_string($sphoto_categories) and then decode it. Otherwise i get json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (In postman of corse, other problem is solved for me)